# Assignment of coulmn by filtering dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to assign a particular value of 1 to feature `country_US` if `country`'s value is 'US'. Here is what two thing I tried but getting warning and X_test is also not updated with `country_US` feature.

`X_test[X_test['country']=='US].loc[:,'country_US']=1`

AND

`X_test.loc[X_test['country']=='US].loc[:,'country_US']=1`

WARNING -

C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:671: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that really, for starters:

```py
import numpy as np
#recomended:

X_test['country_US']=np.where(X_test['country'].eq('US'), 1,0)

#less recommended, yet working:

X_test['country_US']=0
X_test.loc[X_test['country'].eq('US'), 'country_US']=[1]
```

Comment: Thanks. But why my code is not working, even after using `loc` attribute

Comment: Because you try to assign value to a copy of a dataframe - which is what you get, if you take `.loc[]` from `.loc[]`

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what Grzegorz Skibinski has suggested, I would like to mention

```
X_test[X_test['country']=='US].loc[:,'country_US']=1
```

Here a semicolon appears to be missing. Also you might try this

```
t=X_test[X_test['country']=='US'] #Returns a dataframe
t['country_US']=1
```

Here, I am using partitioning which helps us to filter easily , because honestly the one-liner is confusing to me.
Hope this helps